# React Hook Form on modal setting default value

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I've got a form on a modal component, using React Hook Form, that has 2 date fields ("visitStart" and "visitEnd"), that is opened from a React Full Calendar component. The issue I'm having is with a date click and passing the values to the form as default values. All in all, it works fine, except that when the modal is opened for the first time, the default values reflect whatever the current date is, rather than the date that was passed to it. Closing the modal and opening again always returns the expected passed date, it is only on the initial opening of the modal after a browser refresh. What is also strange is that no where am I setting for the modal to receive the current date. With RHF, the default values are set on the initial render (which I'm assuming to be the issue involved), but I have a useEffect to catch the passed date and then reset the fields. I've tried timeouts and being overly redundant in passing the correct date value multiple ways (as a prop and through redux), but cannot seem to get past the first time the modal is opened it showing the current date. Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong are appreciated. For what its worth, I have an event click that triggers a similar modal that works as expected, I've included the function for the event click handler as well just for reference.

Parent component with React Full Calendar passing date value (currently being passed directly as a prop and also passing through redux, yes redundant, but still trying to get this to work):

```
const handleDateClick = (arg) => {
        console.log("1: ", arg.dateStr)

        // eslint-disable-next-line
        let dateNoTime = new Date(arg.dateStr.replace(/-/g, '\/'))
        console.log("2: ", dateNoTime)

        let dateTime = new Date();
        dateNoTime.setHours(dateTime.getHours());
        dateNoTime.setMinutes(dateTime.getMinutes());
        dateNoTime.setSeconds(0);

        console.log("3: ", dateNoTime)
        let adjust = new Date(dateNoTime).toISOString()
        console.log("4: ", adjust)
        setHasDate(adjust)
        let payloadObj = {
            open: true,
            time: adjust
        }
        dispatch(setScheduleOpenState(payloadObj))
        
    }

    const handleEventClick = (arg) => {
    
        const visitId = arg.event.extendedProps.visitId
        // console.log("visitId: ", visitId, "event: ", arg.event.extendedProps)
        setVisitId(visitId)
        setEventDetails(arg.event.extendedProps) 
        dispatch(setOpenState(true))
    }
    console.log("hasDate: ", hasDate)
        
    const singleEvent = 
            <div>
                <ViewVisit 
                    event={eventDetails} 
                    isOpen={isOpen}
                    visitId={visitId}
                />
            </div>

    const dateSchedule = 
            <div>
                <ScheduleVisit
                    isOpen={schedulerOpen}
                    hasDate={hasDate}
                />
            </div>
```

Modal receiving the date:

```
export default function ScheduleVisit({hasDate, isOpen}) {

  ...
  const hasTime = useSelector(state => state.visit.schedulerTime)

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasTime) {
        // reset()
      resetField("visitStart", { defaultValue: hasTime})
      resetField("visitEnd", { defaultValue: hasTime})
    } else {
        reset()
    }
  }, [hasTime])

  const { control, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }, resetField, reset } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
    client: '',
    user: '',
    location: '',
    visitStart: hasDate,
    visitEnd: hasDate,
    status: 'Scheduled'
    }
  });
```

The behavior after a browser refresh:
[image: first run]
and the log values (hasDate is from the parent calendar component, in scheduler is the modal, the 2 values are the one received through redux and the 2nd as the one received by passing the prop):

- hasDate:  2024-03-12T23:27:00.000Z
- in scheduler:  undefined undefined
- in scheduler:  undefined 2024-03-12T23:27:00.000Z
- hasDate:  2024-03-12T23:27:00.000Z
- in scheduler:  2024-03-12T23:27:00.000Z undefined
- in scheduler:  2024-03-12T23:27:00.000Z 2024-03-12T23:27:00.000Z

And for any click after the first following the browser refresh:
[image: 2nd]

- hasDate:  2024-03-12T23:32:00.000Z
- in scheduler:  undefined undefined
- in scheduler:  undefined 2024-03-12T23:32:00.000Z
- hasDate:  2024-03-12T23:32:00.000Z
- in scheduler:  2024-03-12T23:32:00.000Z undefined
- in scheduler:  2024-03-12T23:32:00.000Z 2024-03-12T23:32:00.000Z

Just not sure what I'm missing to get the control over the initial view, and also where its showing the current date value since that's never passed to the component, or assigned to anything within the component.